# Sketch the graph of the following peridoic function and find its Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, graphing-functions

I think I've the graph wrong, just struggling with the Fourier series. 
[image: question]

Comment: What are you exactly struggling with?

Comment: Can you upload what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is even on $[-\pi,\pi]$. So you end up with a Fourier cosine series only. For $n=1,2,3,\cdots$,
$$
         a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(n x)dx \\= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0}(\pi +x)\cos(n x)dx + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-x)\cos(n x)dx
$$
For $n=0$,
$$
        a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0}(\pi +x)dx+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-x)dx.
$$

The Fourier series is

$$
      f \sim \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cos(n\pi x).
$$